# Retrain Mobilenet_v1 for additional classes / synsets

Tags: tensorflow, training-data

I read a lot of tutorials about retraining Mobilenet in TensorFlow by using our own dataset and the pre-trained ImageNet 1000 model file.

The problem I met is, saying I created an additional 10 synsets as my own dataset, and expected a new binary to classify 1000+10=1010 sysnets. However, all I got is a .pb file for only my 10 sysnets (those in my small dataset).

Someone said that it re-trained the last layer in the graph, and changed its dimension from [, 1000] to [, 10], but can we change it to [, 1010]?

If not, what's the value of retrain or fine-tune, and why not train from scratch instead?

I started an expensive machine learning AMI in AWS which costs 2200USD/month, and it can be used to retrain all 1000+10 images from scratch, but I doubt if this is the correct direction.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The best way is to retrain (on a sample of the dataset) on all desired categories.